# Installer jar is not getting executed using the following pom with izpack

Tags: maven, izpack

I tried making an izpack installer using maven. The problem that I'm facing is that in the build the 'install.xml' and the other resources are just being copied to the install.jar. The XML file is not parsed and hence the install.jar is not getting executed.

Please help in rectifying the issue.
pom.xml

```
`<groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>izpack-dist-test-harness</artifactId>
    <name>IzPack dist module</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
            <artifactId>izpack-standalone-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
            <artifactId>izpack-utils</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-beta5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/izpack</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>

        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
                <artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>izpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <izpackBasedir>${staging.dir}</izpackBasedir>
                            <descriptor>install.xml</descriptor>
                            <installerFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-install.jar</installerFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
                        <artifactId>izpack-standalone-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>4.3.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-install-xml-parsed</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${staging.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <delimiters>
                                <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                            </delimiters>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/izpack/</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>install.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>'
    <properties>
        <staging.dir>${basedir}/target/staging</staging.dir>
    </properties>
</project>`
```

And the part of install.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1' standalone='yes' ?>
<installation version='1.0'>
<info>
    <!-- Info Params -->
</info>

<variables>
    <variable name="RESOURCEROOT" value="src/main/izpack"></variable>
</variables>

<guiprefs resizable="no" width="500" height="500">
    <modifier key="headingImageOnLeft" value="yes"/>
    <modifier key="labelGap" value="2"/>
    <modifier key="useHeadingPanel" value="yes"/>
    <modifier key="headingBackgroundColor" value="0x00ffffff"/>
</guiprefs>

<locale>
    <langpack iso3="eng"/>
    <langpack iso3="fra"/>
    <langpack iso3="spa"/>
</locale>

<resources>
    <res id="HTMLLicencePanel.licence" src="License.txt"/>
    <res id="InfoPanel.info" src="Readme.txt"/>
</resources>

<panels>
    <panel classname="HelloPanel"/>
    <panel classname="HTMLLicencePanel"/>
    <panel classname="InfoPanel"/>
    <panel classname="InstallPanel"/>
    <panel classname="FinishPanel"/>
</panels>

<conditon type="java" id="installonwindows">
    <java>
        <class>com.izforge.izpack.util.OsVersion</class>
        <field>IS_WINDOWS</field>
    </java>
    <returnvalue type="boolean">true</returnvalue>
</conditon>

<installerrequirements>
    <installerrequiremnet conditon="installonwindows" message="This installer can install only on windows"/>
</installerrequirements>

<packs>
    <pack name="Base" required="yes" preselected="yes">
        <description>The Base Files</description>
        <file src="Readme.txt" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH" override="asktrue"/>
        <file src="Licence.txt" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH" override="asktrue"/>
    </pack>
</packs>
```

Any Help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!